# How to insert icon into interface?

Tags: java, swing

I need some help with solving out if it's possible to create an ArrayList<> of Icons, and then using those Icons and print them out in an interface JLabel.
What I am trying to do is to make 3 buttons on which it says red, green and blue. When you press a button, it makes a square in that color. If I press multiple times, it makes multiple squares without deleting the previous ones.

```
redBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    icon.addIcon(new SquareIcon(50, Color.red));
                    label.setIcon(icon.getIcon(icon.getIconsSize()));
                    System.out.println(icon.getIconsSize());
                    frame.repaint();
                    frame.pack();
            }
    });
```

this is the red button, and as you can see, when I press it, I add a new icon to the ArrayList. After, I try to set the label to that icon by getting the icon on a certain index in the arraylist, and I get the index number by finding out the size of the arraylist and minus it with 1 (since an arraylist starts on 0).

I use the println to test if it's actually being added to the arraylist.

But I still cannot make it appear on the interface? And also, would it work with multiple Icons?

---

**Edit:**
I am trying to make multiple squares appear in the window (JFrames I think they're called?) when you click multiple times on the buttons. Anyway, you are saying that I can create the icons only once, and then make a new JLabel everytime I click on a button, and store them in a list, and then fill the JLabels out with one of the icons?

Comment: You only need three Icon objects, a redIcon, blueIcon, and a greenIcon, and you only need to create them once since they can be used multiple times. As for the rest of your problem, I'm not clear on your actual exact requirements, for instance, multiple squares, where? Also, why an ArrayList of Icons? Why not a List of JLabels? or Rectangle2D objects? Please describe more of your program structure.

Comment: I am trying to make multiple squares appear in the window (JFrames I think they're called?) when you click multiple times on the buttons. Anyway, you are saying that I can create the icons only once, and then make a new JLabel everytime I click on a button, and store them in a list, and then fill the JLabels out with one of the icons?

Comment: Please see answer below. No need to use a List even.

Answer (score 2):

You state:

> I need some help with solving out if it's possible to create an ArrayList<> of Icons, and then using those Icons and print them out in an interface JLabel.

Perhaps this is not the best way to solve your problem...

> What I am trying to do is to make 3 buttons on which it says red, green and blue. When you press a button, it makes a square in that color. If I press multiple times, it makes multiple squares without deleting the previous ones.

Suggestions:

- I don't think that you need an ArrayList of Icons.
- Again, only create three Icon objects and variables, a redIcon, greenIcon, and blueIcon
- Each time the blue JButton is pressed, create a new JLabel with the blueIcon and add it to the JPanel that is displaying the labels.
- After adding or removing a component from the containing JPanel, don't forget to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the containing JPanel. The `revalidate()` tells the JPanel to re-lay out all of its components including the new ones added, and the `repaint()` call helps to paint over any "dirty" regions on the container that need to be cleaned up.
- Note that you can re-use the same ImageIcon multiple times in multiple JLabels.

Comment: Thanks a ton to both of you! You were both absolutely right about how to do it :)

I think my main problem was that I misunderstood how the icons worked! But your explanation was perfect!